# VBA Checkbox Additional code

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I was wandering, if it was possible to add another event to a checkbox in VBA Excel. I create a checkbox like this:

```
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(.Left, .Top,.Width, .Height).Select
With Selection
    .Caption = ""
    .LinkedCell = "AN2"
    .Value = xlOn
End With
```

I was wondering if I could add code to it, so that whenever someone checks it, some cell would get the current date like:

```
Cells(1,"A").Now()
```

Cheers!

Comment: Just assign the name of a macro that does what you want to its `OnAction` property

Comment: Thanks, was just was i was looking for, didnt know it had this emmbed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rory mentioned, the answear was :

add ".OnAction = "Name of macro" and then you can write a macro that coresponds to the click:

```
With Selection
    .Caption = ""
    .LinkedCell = "AN2"
    .Value = xlOff
    .OnAction = "DateClicked"
End With

Function DateClicked()
    If Cells(2,"AN") = "TRUE" Then
        Cells(2,"A") = Now()
    Else 
        Cells(2,"A") = ""
    End If
End Function
```